# What is the right place for checking a resource presence in Spring REST MVC project?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Spring REST MVC project that consists of repositories, models, services, and controllers.
After code review there was discovered that resource existence is checked on different layers (the most in services and controllers).

Is it OK to have code below in a few layers, or it should be in one place?

```
if (resource == null) {
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should be placed in one particular layer. Personally I would choose services. Why? This is the place where the resource is really looked for. It's the service job to find a resource or throw an appropriate exception. Endpoint/controller should be used to only receive the request and return a response - should be as dummy as possible. Most of the work should be done in services.

Basically you can put such logic in a chosen layer, but one and the same for all resources.